# Plot many histograms using a for loop in R

Tags: r, statistics, histogram, data-analysis

I have a .csv file with data like this:

```
         RI    Na   Mg   Al    Si    K    Ca   Ba   Fe Type
1   1.51793 12.79 3.50 1.12 73.03 0.64  8.77 0.00 0.00  BWF
2   1.51643 12.16 3.52 1.35 72.89 0.57  8.53 0.00 0.00  VWF
3   1.51793 13.21 3.48 1.41 72.64 0.59  8.43 0.00 0.00  BWF
4   1.51299 14.40 1.74 1.54 74.55 0.00  7.59 0.00 0.00  TBL
5   1.53393 12.30 0.00 1.00 70.16 0.12 16.19 0.00 0.24 BWNF
6   1.51655 12.75 2.85 1.44 73.27 0.57  8.79 0.11 0.22 BWNF
```

I want to create histograms for the distribution of each of the columns.
I've tried this:

```
data<-read.csv("glass.csv")
names<-(attributes(data)$names)
for(name in names)
{
    dev.new()
    hist(data$name)
}
```

But i keep getting this error: `Error in hist.default(data$name) : 'x' must be numeric`

I'm assuming that this error is because `attributes(data)$names` returns a set of strings, `"RI"   "Na"   "Mg"   "Al"   "Si"   "K"    "Ca"   "Ba"   "Fe"   "Type"`

But I'm unable to convert them to the necessary format.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close. I think you were also trying to get `Type` at the end.

```
data<-read.csv("glass.csv")
# names<-(attributes(data)$names)
names<-names(data)
classes<-sapply(data,class)

for(name in names[classes == 'numeric'])
{
    dev.new()
    hist(data[,name]) # subset with [] not $
}
```

You could also just loop through the columns directly:

```
for (column in data[class=='numeric']) {
    dev.new()
    hist(column)
}
```

But `ggplot2` is designed for multiple plots. Try it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(data),aes(x=value)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than drawing lots of histograms, a better solution is to draw one plot with histograms in panels.

For this, you'll need the `reshape2` and `ggplot2` packages.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
```

First, you'll need to convert your data from wide to long form.

```
long_data <- melt(data, id.vars = "Type", variable.name = "Element")
```

Then create a ggplot of the `value` argument (you can change the name of this by passing `value.name = "whatever"` in the call to `melt` above) with histograms in each panel, split by each element.

```
(histograms <- ggplot(long_data, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~ Element)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`hist(data$name)` looks for a column named `name`, which isn't there. Use `hist(data[,name])` instead.